# Table Text Wraping and shading

Tags: tables

I'm currently attempting to construct a table which features multiple columns and rows.
My code is the following:

```
\blindtext
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.6cm}}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Activities} & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{This is the title}    \\ \cline{2-11} 
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{16/17} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{17/18} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{18/19} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19/20} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{20/21} \\ \cline{2-11} 
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\nth{2} S.}  &\nth{1} S. & \nth{2} S. & \nth{1} S. & \nth{2} S. & \nth{1} S. & \nth{2} S. & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\nth{1} S.}        \\ \hline
1. First Text          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}}  & \cellcolor{lightgray} & & & & & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}}2. Second Text\\  2.1 Text too big and should be wrapped\\ 2.2 Text too big and should be wrapped\\ 2.3 Text too big and should be wrapped\\ 2.4 Text too big and should be wrapped\\ \end{tabular} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & \cellcolor{lightgray} & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}}3 Third Text\\ 3.1 Third.1 Text \end{tabular} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray} & & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}}4 Fourth Text\\ 4.1 Fourth.1 Text that should be wrapped \end{tabular} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray} & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}}5 Fifth Text\\ 5.1 Fifth.1 Text \end{tabular} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & \cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray} & & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline
6. Another Text          &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline
7. Another Text          &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &  &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}}  \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}8 Another Text \\ 8.1 Another Text\\ 8.2 Another Text\\ 8.3 Another Text \end{tabular} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Activities Schedule}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

Now I'm facing two problems:

- The text is not wrapping when it should. And if I specify the column width for the first column of each tabular I get a left padding as i remove the @{}.
- As you can see from the picture, whenever i set the cellcolor i lose the original border color (and that is not my intention).

[image: Color Problem]

Can anybody help me as i am new to Latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The text that does not wrap is due to your incorrect (and also superfluous) usage of nested tabulars without  column specifier. The lost lines around colored cells might be a viewer issue (try zooming in and see what hapens).

Comment: To overcome the first issue, use `\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5cm}}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{@{}}` or remove the nested tabulars altogether.

Comment: Also, please never ever ignore error messages! (`! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble. <to be read again> \cr l.26 \begin{tabular}{@{}}` in case of your table) Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. It is now working !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tabular and friends

Here is your tabular using `tabular` and different packages. The disappearing lines behind the gray cell background is a viewer artefact. If you increase zoom-level to 200 (or 300) per cent, you will normally see the lines. If this is not an option, you should take a look ad the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) which handles tabulars with background colours and lines without problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3.1cm, right=3.1cm]{geometry} % narrow margins
\usepackage{multirow, array, caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\newcommand{\gray}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Activity Schedule}
\label{table-1}
\small % smaller text
\begin{tabular}{|l @{\hspace{0.7em}}>{\raggedright}p{3.5cm}|*{10}{l|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}                             & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{This is the title}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \cline{3-12} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Activities}                             & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{16/17}                                                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{17/18}                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{18/19}                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19/20}                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{20/21}                          \\ \cline{3-12} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & 2\textsuperscript{nd}                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{S.}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\textsuperscript{st} S.}                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2\textsuperscript{nd} S.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\textsuperscript{st} S.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2\textsuperscript{nd} S.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\textsuperscript{st} S.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2\textsuperscript{nd} S.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\textsuperscript{st}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{S.}  \\ \hline
1.      & First text                               & \gray & \gray & \gray &                             &                             &                             &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ \hline
2.      & Second text                              &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    &                             &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ %\hline
2.1     & Text too big and should be wrapped       &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    &                             &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ %\hline
2.2     & Text too big and should be wrapped       &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    &                             &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ %\hline
2.3     & Text too big and should be wrapped       &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    &                             &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ %\hline
2.4     & Text too big and should be wrapped       &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    &                             &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ \hline
3.      & Third text                               &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    & \gray    &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ %\hline
3.1     & Third 1. text                            &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    & \gray    &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ \hline
4.      & Fourth text                               &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             &                             & \gray    & \gray    &                             &                          &                          \\ %\hline
4.1     & Fourth 1. Text that should be wrapped     &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             &                             & \gray    & \gray    &                             &                          &                          \\ \hline
5.      & Fifth text                               &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    & \gray    &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ %\hline
5.1     & Fifth 1. text                            &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             & \gray    & \gray    &                             &                             &                          &                          \\ \hline
6.      & Another text                             &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             &                             &                             &                             & \gray    &                          &                          \\ \hline
7.      & Another text                             &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 & \gray    & \gray    & \gray    & \gray    & \gray    & \gray & \gray \\ \hline
8.      & Another text                             &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             &                             &                             &                             &                             & \gray & \gray \\ %\hline
8.1     & Another text                             &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             &                             &                             &                             &                             & \gray & \gray \\ %\hline
8.2     & Another text                             &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             &                             &                             &                             &                             & \gray & \gray \\ %\hline
8.3     & Another text                             &                                                 &                                                 &                                                 &                             &                             &                             &                             &                             & \gray & \gray \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### cals

Here is the same tabular build using the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

```
\documentclass[DIV=10]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor, caption, ragged2e}
\usepackage[british]{babel}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\RaggedRight
\caption{Activity Schedule}\medskip
\label{table-1}
\begin{calstable}
% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*32\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 128 

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}

\def\gray{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\rp{\ifx\cals@paddingR\empty    % Right padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}

% R1
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \nc{lt}
    \nc{rt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{This is the title}
\erow
\brow
    \nc{l}
    \nc{r}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{16/17}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{17/18}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{18/19}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{19/20}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{20/21}
\erow
\mdseries
\brow
    \nc{lb}
    \nc{rb}\alignC\sc{\vfil \bfseries Activities}
    \scriptsize\cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd}}
    \cell{\vfill S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st}}
    \cell{\vfill S.}\normalsize
\erow
}

% R2 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{1.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{First text}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R3 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{2.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Second text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.2}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.3}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.4}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R8 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{3.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Third text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R9 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{3.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Third 1. text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R10 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{4.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Forth text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R11 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{4.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Fourth 1. text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R12 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{5.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Fifth text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R13 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{5.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Fifth 1. text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R14 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{6.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R15 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{7.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R16 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{8.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R17 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{8.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R18 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{8.2}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R19 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{8.3}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Breakable cals

Here is a `calstable` that will break at bottom of the page. You may fill in a continuation message, but on my system, it showed under the tabular on the second page two. Maybe it is best to avoid that message, see the definition of `\tfoot{}`:

```
\documentclass[DIV=10]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor, caption, ragged2e, lipsum}
\usepackage[british]{babel}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent


\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1-2]

%\begin{table}[!htb]
{\RaggedRight
\captionaboveof{table}{Activity Schedule}\medskip
\label{table-1}
\begin{calstable}
% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*32\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/128*9\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 128 

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}

\def\gray{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\rp{\ifx\cals@paddingR\empty    % Right padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}

% R1
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \nc{lt}
    \nc{rt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{This is the title}
\erow
\brow
    \nc{l}
    \nc{r}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{16/17}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{17/18}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{18/19}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{19/20}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{20/21}
\erow
\mdseries
\brow
    \nc{lb}
    \nc{rb}\alignC\sc{\vfil \bfseries Activities}
    \scriptsize\cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd}}
    \cell{\vfill S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 2\textsuperscript{nd} S.}
    \cell{\vfill 1\textsuperscript{st}}
    \cell{\vfill S.}\normalsize
\erow
}
\tfoot{%
    \lastrule%\nointerlineskip%
    \textit{\strut Activity Schedule continues on next page% You may delete this line
    }%
    \par%
    }
% R2 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{1.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{First text}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R3 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{2.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Second text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.2}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.3}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{2.4}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Text ist too long and should be wrapped}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R8 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{3.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Third text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R9 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{3.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Third 1. text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R10 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{4.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Forth text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R11 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{4.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Fourth 1. text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R12 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{5.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Fifth text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
% R13 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{5.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Fifth 1. text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R14 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{6.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}\gray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R15 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{7.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R16 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{8.}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R17 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{8.1}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R18 Body
\brow
    \rb\alignL\cell{8.2}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
% R19 Body
\brow
    \bb\rb\alignL\cell{8.3}\rb
    \alignL\cell{Another text}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \gray\cell{}
    \cell{}\gray
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular
}%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I might try this instead of the first solution as even when i export to pdf it outputs a cleaner look.

Comment: I've already set the table as per your instructions but know I'm facing a problem: If the table doesn't fit the table it doesn't brake. Instead it skips the section and moves to another page where it can fit entirely. Using \longtable instead of \table breaks my compiler. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @DiogoRibeiro At least you you have to remove the table-environment. This environment hinder the table from breaking. You use the KOMA-script command `\captionaboveof{float type}[entry]{title}` to have a caption, see the manual page 132. I have published updated code, that breaks. You may also break manually by using a `\tbreak{}` command